# UDP client/server combined C project

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have a very easy assignment that I have theoretically completed: A chat program that uses UDP to communicate. It is up to us to implement whatever features we want and I will try my best to implement them on my own but I seem to be having a hard time implementing the core idea: A program that is both server and client.

Everywhere I look, I see two separate applications for UDP datagram exchange. It is always client.c and server.c and I was wondering why.
[image: Simple Chat Protocol diagram]

This is the diagram I came up with. Basically, I am using the state machine model and events to change states.

Can you tell me why I haven't been able to find an example where the START state of a program is both LISTEN and SEND? I can't see a reason why it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Because you haven't looked hard enough, or you're looking for the wrong thing, or over-specifying the problem. This is not a programming question, just a question about your own immediate past history.

Comment: @EJP Not hard enough? I have tried to search using many keywords and looked through pages. Even Beej's pages (http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html#simpleserver) provide two programs. Let me rephrase the question for you: can you provide a combined UDP client/server example?

Comment: @user2899235 Most examples will normally be just that, examples. As such they are as small and isolated as possible. For sockets, one natural way to isolate examples is in dividing them into a client and server. But you're absolutely right. Nothing is stopping you from creating a program that acts as a client and a server, and a lot of real programs act that way.

Comment: @nos Thank you! This is the response I was expecting. Not having seen any examples that combined the two, I thought I was missing something crucial. And it just makes sense to create a program that acts as both. I wish this was an Answer instead of a Comment so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you have not been able to find any example. In most topologies, server-client, p2p, etc. all peers send and receive. Why here is an example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16935/A-Chat-Application-Using-Asynchronous-UDP-sockets

Comment: nice, but my question was for c